# How to divide two DataFrames by key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a pandas problem. Given two dataframes, for example like this:

```
A = 
key    val  
-----------
spam    10
eggs    20 
ham     30


B = 
key    val
-----------
eggs    2
spam    1
ham     3
```

Note that the rows are permuted.

How can I divide `A.val / B.val` so the result is:

```
key    val
-----------
spam    10
eggs    10
ham     10
```

In words, the values are divided if their keys match. Order of rows does not matter.

Comment: are you trying to divide? I can't tell because 10/2 is 5 not 10. So are you doing basic division or is there something else you have in mind?

Comment: @RyanSaxe he divedes according to key, so result is correct

Comment: @RyanSaxe The whole point is that the rows are permuted, so I don't want to divide the values in the same place but the values with the same keys.

Comment: @alko wow my bad for not reading very carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [pandas dataframe merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra):

```
merged = pd.merge(A,B,on="key")
answer = merged['val_x']/merged['val_y']
```

now `answer` is a series with the values you wanted and you can create a new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(merged['key'],answer))
#print df
0  eggs  10
1   ham  10
2  spam  10

#left out header because I used 0 and 1, not key and value, but you get the point, it works!
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method to make dataframes match by key during division:

```
>>> res = A.set_index('key') / B.set_index('key')
>>> res
      val
key      
eggs   10
ham    10
spam   10
```

And then you can [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) back

```
>>> res.reset_index()
    key  val
0  eggs   10
1   ham   10
2  spam   10
```

Comment: Thanks. OP didn't provide a test case, I had an error in my setup, and receiving wrong result decided that this method do not work.

Comment: this is very clever. Is there a significant difference between this and merging? As far as memory exhaust goes, since this does not create a new `DataFrame`. and @alko merging does work in this case, i tested it out and had no problem.

Comment: @RyanSaxe I removed my answer, as despite the fact it works, this way you don't have to mess with column names